# Unity move camera in game topdown not smooth

Tags: unity-game-engine

when i create a game with unity, i add script to main camera, but when i drag move on game, it was drag too snowly and not smooth.Some one help me!

Here my script:

```
    public int dragSpeed = 20;
    private Vector3 _dragOrigin;

    void Update()
    {
        SetDragScreen();
    }

    void SetDragScreen()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            _dragOrigin = Input.mousePosition;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && _dragOrigin != Vector3.zero)
        {
            Vector3 diff = _dragOrigin - Input.mousePosition;
            if (diff.magnitude > 0f)
            {
                if (Camera.main != null)
                {
                    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(diff);
                    Vector3 move = new Vector3(-pos.x, 0, -pos.y) * dragSpeed;

                    Vector3 newPosition = Camera.main.transform.position + move;
                    Camera.main.transform.Translate(move, Space.World);
                }

                _dragOrigin = Input.mousePosition;
            }
        }

        if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            _dragOrigin = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
        }

        if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved && _dragOrigin != Vector3.zero)
        {
            Vector3 diff = _dragOrigin - new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 0);
            if (diff.magnitude > 0f)
            {
                Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(diff);
                Vector3 move = new Vector3(-pos.x, 0, -pos.y) * dragSpeed;


                Vector3 newPosition = Camera.main.transform.position + move;
                Camera.main.transform.Translate(move, Space.World);
                _dragOrigin = Input.mousePosition;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) || (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended))
        {
            _dragOrigin = Vector3.zero;
        }
    }
```

please see my script and give me some solution, thank all.
i want to drag smooth and when i click and drag, but i stop drag (not mouseup) i want pause drag until i continue drag mouse after

Comment: try using cinemachine then